# Inequality for an integral

Tags: real-analysis

How to prove that the function $$f(r)=(1 - r^2) \int_0^{2\pi}|Re[\frac{e^{i a} (2 - e^{-i s} r)}{(-e^{i s} + r)^2}]|ds$$ for real $a$ and $r\in[0,1]$ attains its maximum for $r=0$ with $f(0)=8$.

Comment: Could you give some more background to this problem? Surely this is not a randomly chosen integral; is this an exercise, or a step in the proof of a larger result?

Comment: A step on the proof of the following inequality $|f'(z)-f'(0)|\le \frac{8|z|}{\pi(1-|z|^2)} \max|f(z)|$, where $f$ is analytic in the unit disk.

Comment: OK, so this looks like an exercise from a book. If so, then I think http://math.stackexchange.com would be a more suitable site for this question.

Comment: Not an exercise, I am guessing that this is true but probably a problem which no one can solve it.

Comment: If that's (= your comment) what you're after, then Cauchy's formula seems to give a better estimate quite easily.

Comment: It should be $|f'(z)-f'(0)|\le \frac{4|z|}{\pi(1-|z|^2)} \max|f(z)|$ instead.

Comment: When you say you guess this is true, how did you guess these exact constants?

Comment: @ Yemon Choi By using Cauchy formula, you obtain the function $f(r)$, and mathematica 8 software tells us that the maximum of $f$ is in $0$.